# informix update based on values in another table

Tags: informix

I have the following select statement that works just fine:

```
select stock_master.stock_code, stk_stock_status, reorder_buyer, default_route_id, main_work_centre
from stock_master, bill_of_materials_header, production_routing
where stock_master.stock_code = bill_of_materials_header.stock_code
  and bill_of_materials_header.default_route_id = production_routing.prh_route_id
  and main_work_centre != "CNC";
  and stock_group >= 3201 and stock_group <= 3299;
```

What I want to do is update the stk_stock_status to "M" for this condition, but can't seem to work out the correct syntax for the update command.  Any pointers would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `stk_stock_status` is in`stock_master` table and this table has some ID column then convert your select into select that returns only identifiers which should be updated. It will look like:

```
UPDATE stock_master SET stk_stock_status = 'M' WHERE stk_stock_id IN
(
SELECT stk_stock_id
FROM stock_master, bill_of_materials_header, production_routing
WHERE stock_master.stock_code = bill_of_materials_header.stock_code
  AND bill_of_materials_header.default_route_id = production_routing.prh_route_id
  AND main_work_centre != 'CNC';
)
```

PS Do not use `"` for sting literals. It is allowed by Informix but not by SQL standard. Better use `'`.